# Hadoop reduce before map task completed

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

It's known that receive words in map task and sum up those "one" in reduce task in WordCount example.

I've tried adding System.out.println to show how wordcount example code running in map/reduce task. When I read stdout log at webpage of jobtracker, I noticed that some "sum up" work executed before map task completed and redo "sum up" those sum at the map task in reduce task.

Even though it does not effect the result in the wordcount example,it may a trouble at other works.(Do same work twice!)

I've modified "mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps", but it doesn't work.

Is any configuration about this problem ?

Comment: Although I don't fully understand your question, I suggest you to read this tutorial: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html . Maybe you are talking about the Combiner.

Comment: Maybe you also use the reducer class as a combiner? Combiners are executed several times after mapper for reducing the intermediate results from mappers to reducers.

Comment: Yes! The answer is the Combiner. There is the line "job.setCombinerClass" I've not thought carefully.Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the advantages of MapReduce and Hadoop is the ability for Nodes to act independently when given enough information. In the case of Mappers and Reducers often times the Reducer can be started even without all of the Mappers completing first.

The work will not be duplicated!

The percentage of Mappers that need to be completed before Reducers can be scheduled by be set by using the option, "mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps", or with the new API "[mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.7/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)".

If you have combiners, then the story is similar, no work will be duplicated.  But, since combiners are optimizations that run on the Mapper Nodes, then several combiners might be getting called as they perform their operations (most likely a sum, or a merge of some sort).  So with combiners, it's possible to see multiple combine operations occurring even if you have told your Reducers not to start untill 100% of the Mappers have completed.